# What is the correct way to use the "bool" param type with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have been trying to make use of the param types with ui-router and can't seem to get them right.

`$stateProvider.state({ 
    name: 'home.foo', 
    url: '/foo/{isBar:bool}', 
    controller: function() { }, 
    templateUrl: 'foo.html'
    });`

My expectation is that I should be able to transition to that state like this:

`$state.go(home.foo, { isBar: false })`

or

`ui-sref="home.foo({ isBar: false })"`

however in the resulting $stateParams you will see isBar: true

Looking at the way the 'bool' [param type is written](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/urlMatcherFactory.js#L583) I suppose true/false should be encoded as 0/1 on the url but this doesn't happen. If use 0/1 in the params for $state.go then it works and is decoded as false/true but to further confuse the issue this doesn't work if using the ui-sref.

Hopefully this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WWo34b8Crmm7st9XO4oF?p=preview) will explain it better. Any hints appreciated!

Edit: My goal in using the bool param type is to end up with a boolean data type in $stateParams

Comment: This is buggy behavior in 0.2.13 and was fixed in this commit: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/b0c6aa2350fdd3ce8483144774adc12f5a72b7e9 .  If you build from master, your plunk works.  http://plnkr.co/edit/u3NsF0PSmNt3HWiQkdvP?p=preview

Comment: Hey, thanks Chris! Would that also close off this issue for you? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1655

Answer (score 11):

There is an [updated and working plunker with **`boolean`**](http://plnkr.co/edit/w5fHQbaFU4VaXkTxyBGq?p=preview) custom type

In case, we would like to work with a **bool** like type, which 
expects and accepts the:

> **`true`**, **`false`**, **`0`**, **`1`**

we just have to register our custom type:

```
app.config(['$urlMatcherFactoryProvider', function($urlMatcherFactory) {

  $urlMatcherFactory.type('boolean',
    // our type custom type
    {
     name : 'boolean',
     decode: function(val) { return val == true ? true : val == "true" ? true : false },
     encode: function(val) { return val ? 1 : 0; },
     equals: function(a, b) { return this.is(a) && a === b; },
     is: function(val) { return [true,false,0,1].indexOf(val) >= 0 },
     pattern: /bool|true|0|1/
    })

}]);
```

And then we can use this url defintion inside of any state:

```
...
, url: '/foo/{isBar:boolean}'
...
```

*NOTE: why `boolean`? not `bool`? Because `bool` is already registered for `0|1` as far as I remember*

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/w5fHQbaFU4VaXkTxyBGq?p=preview)

*ORIGINAL*

simple solution working with "strings" [in this updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/c0269e8oE4C9TVs5uWVf?p=preview),

```
... // states definitions
, url: '/foo/{isBar:(?:bool|true|0|1)}'
```

Comment: The type in $stateParam is a string though. I realise now that I am not explicit in my question but the result I am after is { isBar : true/false }

Comment: The power of `UI-Router` is unlimited ;) Enjoy it ;)

Comment: Thanks Radim, it looks like more than I was after :) I did look at registering a custom type but wanted to try and understand why the default bool was not working first. I still don't quite understand what it is supposed to achieve or if it is just broken!

Comment: **Luckily you have your answer with `boolean`** ;) if you want to know more, observe the source code here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/master/src. Good luck with UI-Router ;)

Comment: Thanks @RadimKöhler. I wonder if it can detect when a querystring is `undefined`. For example `/foo?{isBar:boolean}` to give `false` when the actual url is `/foo` without querystring. I am trying to figure it out now. As far as I have tested, `undefined` does not match in `$state.includes`.

Comment: I missed out the `params` object in `$stateProvider` configuration. Looks like we can set default value there. So problem solved :)

Comment: can $urlMatcherFactory.type('boolean' <-------- can this be whatever you want? or does it have to be boolean,string etc....? Also what's the diff between that and the "name" property in the object?

Answer (score 1):

So after digging around multiple files I found why the last two ways (0,1) don't work in ui-sref.   There is this call at line 106 of stateDirectives.js: `newHref = $state.href(ref.state, params, options);`

This will return null in the case of using 1 and 0.  And since the above call is followed by this:

```
 if (newHref === null) {
      nav = false;
      return false;
    }
```

a link is never made.  Now, the reason null is returned.  state.href calls urlRouter.href.  Inside that is a call to validate the params.  The validation is this:  `result = result && (isOptional || !!param.type.is(val));`

when you look at the is function for bool (`is: function(val) { return val === true || val === false; }`) you can see why this fails as 1 and 0 do not equal true or false.  In my opinion it should also check for 1 and 0 if that is what it is ultimately converted to but at least now you know why it behaves the way it does.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I have updated the plunker to include an example using $state.go however it is the same behaviour as ui-sref. In my more complicated application the 0/1 does decode to false/true correctly. I will continue to try and replicate that in the plunker.