# How to create nested state dynamically based on $stateParams in angular UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to create sub-state (nested states) based on the state params being passed.

For example I have a dynamic state parameter, **`'pageId'`**. If the `$stateparams.pageId` is `'page2'`, then I want to have two nested states created for that.

How can I do that?  Thanks in advance.

Here is the plunkr created for this

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/E6UPIDQpSST9yibtnaWy?p=preview)

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $stateProvider.state('page', {
            url: '/:pageId',
            templateUrl: function($stateParams){
              return $stateParams.pageId +".tpl.html";
            }
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page1');
    }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GLVpLHzzPruP2DDmvqD6?p=preview)

We can create two states. One will NOT use nested views, the second will have them.

```
// state without nested
.state('pageWithout', {
  url: '/{pageId:(?:page1|page3|page5)}',
  templateUrl: "page1.tpl.html",
})
// state with nested
.state('pageWith', {
  url: '/:pageId',
  views : {
    '' : {
      templateUrl: "page2.tpl.html",
    },
    '@pageWith' : {
      template: "<h2>the SECOND content for state with nested views</h2",
    }
  }
});
```

So, the trick is to use some pattern to say which pageId values should go to first state. Check the

#### [UrlMatcher](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type:UrlMatcher)

which is responsible for the **`url : 'url def...'`** processing

And this way we will have similar links translated into different states, with different nested view structure:

```
// without nested views
<a href="#/page1">
<a href="#/page3">
<a href="#/page5">

// with nested views
<a href="#/page2">
<a href="#/pageA">
<a href="#/pageB">
```

Check [it here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GLVpLHzzPruP2DDmvqD6?p=preview)

EXEND, with a child state and some defaults. The [udpated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d4iTnQaPTgXtLWnDB7PW?p=preview)

So, we can create few children of our second state:

```
// children
.state('pageWith.defaultChild', {
  url: '/default',
  views : { 
    '' : {
      template: "<h3>the pageWith.defaultChild </h3",
    }
  }
}) 
.state('pageWith.childWithParams', {
  url: '/{id:int}',
  views : {
    '' : {
      template: "<h3>the child with ID param {{$stateParams.id}} </h3",
    }
  }
});
```

Based on this solution:

#### [Redirect a state to default substate with UI-Router in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29491079/1679310)

We can decorate our parent state with **`redirectTo`**

```
.state('pageWith', {
  url: '/:pageId',
  redirectTo: 'pageWith.defaultChild',
  ...
```

And just add this simple listener

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {
      if (to.redirectTo) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go(to.redirectTo, params)
      }
    });
}]);
```

Check the default [state redirect here](http://plnkr.co/edit/d4iTnQaPTgXtLWnDB7PW?p=preview)

Comment: I liked this idea of using UrlMatcher. However, here when you are specifying '@pageWith' with a template, you are not creating a sub state right? 

Lets say I want to create two sub states for page2, with one sub state being the default one. How do we handle this kind of scenario? And, if I want to navigate to any particular sub state?

Comment: We are really close, give me sec

Comment: So, in the updated answer I gave you updated plunker and added a link to some more detailed answer... now you should have that all to start to profit from mighty UI-Router ;)

Comment: I forgot to update the plunker! there is the latest and correct link http://plnkr.co/edit/d4iTnQaPTgXtLWnDB7PW?p=preview

Comment: Super. This is what I wanted. Thanks so much. I didn't get one part. '/{id:int}' can you please explain me this parttern?

Comment: it is (as said in the link to UrlMatcher) - way how to say what is the type of the param - in this case integer... check the doc and this part: `'{' name ':' regexp|type '}' - curly placeholder with regexp or type name. Should the regexp itself contain curly braces, they must be in matched pairs or escaped with a backslash.` Does it help?

Comment: In the UrlMatcher documentation, I couldn't find a specification saying 'int' means integer. I understand that we can use regular expression. But, these types are also available for UrlMatcher?

Comment: I cited that part from the doc above `'{' name ':' regexp|type '}'` ...see the **type** - it means **type name**

Comment: If you want to know how to create custom types: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27182177/1679310... anyhow good luck with UI-Router ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure clearly understand what you are trying to do, is this what you are trying to do ?

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('page', {
            url: '/:pageId',
            templateUrl: function($stateParams){
                return $stateParams.pageId +".tpl.html";
            },
        });
        .state('page.firstchild', {
            url: '/foo', // will have url /:pageId/foo because it inherits from its parent
        })
        .state('page.secondchild', {
            url: '/bar' // same here
        })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page1');
}]);
```

Comment: In this case, it creates firstChild, and secondChild states everytime irrespective of the pageId passed right? I want to create sub states only for page2. In page2.tpl.html, I am putting a ui-view because I want a substate for that. However in page1.tpl.html, I dont want these substates. So, even if I put a ui-view in page1.tpl.html, it shouldn't work. lets say I have separate module itself for each page. So I want to create these states within the config of page2 module only. Hope I made it clear.