# ui-router for routes with ONLY SPECIFIC values

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to build a route for multiple unique landing pages with the following structure

`domain.com/:state/:city/:category`

How can I define the route so that the state, city, and category can be only one of predefined values, aka:

`state = /ca|ma|ak|az|ar .../i
city = /los-angeles|san-francisco|.../i
category = /painting|plumbing|.../i`

These lists are long so having a huge regex doesn't make much sense (or does it?)

Would I use a **rule()** ? **$urlMatcherFactory**? how can I use a function?

any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: define the route using the normal way `/:state/:city/:category` and then check for an accepted value in a resolve or in the controller. If any one of them is invalid, go to 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to go here, is with custom **type**.

As shown in this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27182177/1679310), in case we wan to create some type which is ready to process values **true**, **false**, **1**, **0** as `boolean`, we can define it like this (there is [also working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w5fHQbaFU4VaXkTxyBGq?p=preview)):

```
app.config(['$urlMatcherFactoryProvider', function($urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {

  $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.type('boolean',
    // our type custom type
    {
     name : 'boolean',
     decode: function(val) { return val == true ? true : val == "true" ? true : false },
     encode: function(val) { return val ? 1 : 0; },
     equals: function(a, b) { return this.is(a) && a === b; },
     is: function(val) { return [true,false,0,1].indexOf(val) >= 0 },
     pattern: /bool|true|0|1/
    })

}]);
```

The same way we can define our types

```
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.type('state'   , ...
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.type('city'    , ...
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.type('category', ...
```

And later we can use them for any amount of state defintions:

```
...
.state('mystate', {
    url: 'xxx/{state:state}/{city:city/{category:category}
    ...
```

That all could work because we can define url for [UrlMatcher](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type:UrlMatcher) like this

> **`'{' name ':' regexp|type '}'`** - curly placeholder with regexp or type name. Should the regexp itself contain curly braces, they must be in matched pairs or escaped with a backslash.

So, not only regexp - but also the **`type`** - including our custom one